# getimagesize() after resizing

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

Is there a way to get the image dimension of an image that was just resized?  What I'm foing is taking a file and fitting it to a 48x48 area (note, I said FIT, not scale.)  Once that's done, I need to get the new image's dimension but I don't want to have to write it out to disk, then reading it back in to use.  Is there a way to do it without that step?

$img = new Imagick('file.jpg');
$img->resizeImage(48,48,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1,TRUE);

// this is where I need to get the dimensions of the new image created above, unless it's a perfect square, only one side will be 48 pixels, the other could be less.

Thanks.